# How is Opa handling communication between client and server?

Tags: opa

Is Opa using AJAX or Websockets?  I'm guessing it would be the former.  What if I want to use websockets instead of AJAX?  Or is it similar to [socket.io](http://socket.io) for Javascript - if the browser supports Websockets it uses them, otherwise it falls back to AJAX & Flash sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPA doesn't currently support websockets.

But it's something we considere again, since firefox 6 brings back support for websockets and a fix is proposed for the previous big security issue.

Comment: This is the nice thing about socket.io, it hides the underlying details and uses websockets when its available - websockets being a bit faster than AJAX as I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Opa is using AJAX currently.

Moreover, a think websocket is rarely supported (by browsers) for the moment due to security reason. And the RFC is still in draft.

Opa servers does not support websocket protocol for the moment.

Comment: AJAX is a bit of a kludge (though a very widely used Kluge).  Websockets are much simpler and potentially faster.  More browsers will be supporting websockets in the future.